# Is is possible to customize the share button position of AMP Stories?

Tags: amp-html, amp-story, amp-stories

The AMP Stories framework displays a share button in the top right corner of the page.
[image: AMP Story share button]
Is there a way to remove it, or at least change its position?

The documentation doesn't say anything about that. I also tried targeting it with css, but it's not working.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: As of today you can control the sharing providers that are used once users click this button, but not hide/change the button itself or its position.
Just curious though: why do you want to hide it?

Comment: Alright thanks! I work with a graphic designer who didn't take into account the share button in the mock-ups and used the upper-right corner differently :)